# Using a view controller both as modal view controller and as a tab bar view controller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a view controller alike **contacts** in iPhone. The code is something like this,

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
friendsVC = [[RemittanceFriendsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"RemittanceFriendsView" bundle:nil];
friendsVC.friendsArray = [[RemittanceModel getInstance] friends];
UINavigationController *friendsNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: friendsVC];
[controllers addObject:friendsNVC];
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

The RemittanceFriendsVC is UITableViewController, clicking on a cell takes to details view. I have 'modal' variable set in the ViewController (VC)to know if its loaded as modal or not.  Since its part of a tab bar item, (non modal view) it works fine. But when I am loading it as modal VC, when I click on a table cell, I want to dismissmodalview, but it did not dismiss the modal view.

In the friendVC this is not working,

```
-(void) didPressCancelButton {
        [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

What I wanted to do is, use the same VC as a tab bar item and sometime as a modal VC. Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, it was the problem with the

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

it should be,

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Then it works fine.